# Store Strings longer than 255 in a database in Netbeans

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans

I have a problem with my database. It's a database that you can create with Netbeans. I want to insert a string that is longer than 255 characters. I have seen that you can say `varchar(512)`. But I generate my tables with the `@Entity`-Annotation and attributes in my class.

How can I put longer strings into the database?

I am using Netbeans 8.0.2.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your entity classes use the `@Column` annotation for the fields you want and specify `columnDefinition="VARCHAR(512)"`.

Comment: Thanks for your fast answer.
Is this the right way?
`@Column(columnDefinition = "varchar(512)")
    private String generalText;`
I still get an error...

Comment: I cleaned the database (All my data :(( ) and now it works.
Thank you so much!!